# Set height of div in pixels based off width of browser window in % (jQuery or JS?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I am trying to set up a black border around a webpage. For the left and right side, just making "width: 5%;" in the CSS is fine. But then I want JS/jQuery to work out how many pixels that is, and make that the height of the top and bottom div.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us your code.

Comment: The top and bottom *DIV* or the top and bottom *border*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you

```
var val = $(".leftAndRight").width();
$(".topAndBottom").height(val);
```

Or with one line:

```
$(".topAndBottom").height($(".leftAndRight").width());
```

Comment: I'm new to this site and I'm not sure how everything works but I believe that if this answer was the right one for you, you could mark it as accepted :) I would appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, @user2451586, that's true, you can accept whichever of the answers you feel best answered your question, either this one or one of the others. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the value for the border width programmatically, assign it to all four borders, and also refresh it any time you resize:

```
var width,
    drawBorder = function () {
        var body = $('body'),
            width = body.width() * 0.05;
        body.css('border-width', width + 'px');
    };

drawBorder();

$(window).resize(function () {
    drawBorder();
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MrYUb/)

If you set the left and right width in your stylesheet and then use JS to give the same border width to the top and bottom, unless you use a resize function your left and right borders will change every time you resize but your top and bottom borders will remain fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use .width() to find width without the border and .outerWidth to find the width including the border. I think .outerWidth also gives you the width with the padding you may have to subtract that.